# understanding javascript jquery function to get file duration?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, file, duration

I have a javascript function which correctly gets the file duration of one uploaded file, and I'm trying to repourpose the working function so that I can get the file duration elsewhere but I'm running into issues, my html5 code looks like such:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
<p>Select a .mp3 file</p>
<input type="file" id="file" multiple="multiple"/>

<audio id="audio"></audio>

<p>
  <label>Song Duration:</label>
  <span id="duration"></span>
</p>

<p>
  <label>Tracklist:</label>
  <span id="tracklist"></span>
</p>
```

and my javascript function which gets the duration as soon as the first file is uploaded looks like such:

```
$("#audio").on("canplaythrough", function(e){
    console.log("calculating duration");
    var seconds = e.currentTarget.duration;
    var duration = moment.duration(seconds, "seconds");

    var time = "";
    var hours = duration.hours();
    if (hours > 0) { time = hours + ":" ; }

    time = time + duration.minutes() + ":" + duration.seconds();
    $("#duration").text(time);

    URL.revokeObjectURL(objectUrl);
});
```

I'm trying to copy this function basically since I know it works, and get the duration in seconds of each song in my array of the multiple files uploaded. But If I just try songs[i].duration, that will always yield an "undefined" value, here is a jsfiddle with my full code:

https://jsfiddle.net/gt4wro11/

tldr; I have an array of multiple files the user uploads, and I'm trying to print out the duration of each file in the array. The 
$("#audio").on("canplaythrough", function(e){
function successfully gets the duration of one file, and I'm trying to repurpose it to fit my needs but can't figure out how to get it working.

Thank you for dealing with this long question!

Comment: whatever is in the array, most likely a string from what it looks like, does not have a property named `duration`, you do not provide enough code to actually help you

Comment: @JarrodRoberson check the jsfiddle, it has all my code which should make it clearer. if i print my songs[] array, in console I can see it is a filelist. What Im confused about is how the function(e) gets its filedata, the first 2 lines of that funciton getting var seconds and var duration are confusing, and Im trying to repurpose them to that I can call it with var seconds = songs[i].duration.

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before attempting to ask more questions. **All relevant code must be in the question. External sites go stale.**

Answer (score 2):

`songs[i]` is an instance of [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File), you need an instance of [HTMLAudioElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement).

Whenever the file selection's `change` event is fired, you should read the selected files, create an object URL for each file, and load them by creating invisible `<audio>` elements. Wait until all audio elements' `canplaythough` has fired, then read their durations.

Your code may look somewhat like this: (you may have to edit some parts to track filenames/sizes/etc for each audio)

```js
function loadAudio(url) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var audio = new Audio();
    audio.oncanplaythrough = () => resolve(audio);
    audio.onerror = reject;
    audio.src = url;
  });
}

$("#file").change(function(e){
    var files = e.currentTarget.files;
    var length = songs.length;

    Promise.all(Array.from(files).map(file => loadAudio(URL.createObjectURL(file))))
    .then(audios => {
        console.log("Audio elements: ", audios)
    });
});
```

Comment: thank you this gives me some good info to go off of. I currently have a for loop going from  i = 0; to i = songs[].length, And now in that for loop I have it make an object URL; " objectURL = URL.createObjectURL(songs[i]); ". Im a little lost on the next step though, how should I go about making sure  that canplaythrough has fired?

Comment: You have to work asynchronously, that's for sure. I'd suggest you learn how to work with [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) as they simplify many async tasks and are widely accepted. For each audio element, create a Promise that resolves when their `canplaythrough` fires, then use `Promise.all()` to wait until all Promises have been resolved.